# How to declare and define function that will return one of few custom classes unknown at the compile time?

Tags: c++, class, oop

In C++ I need to create a function that will return an address to an object that will be an instance of different possible class, but I do not know at the compile time what class it will be (depending on the user behavior).

Is there a way to declare and define a function that will return fully functional address to object with access to its methods of this unknown class?

I already tried to use boost::variant (example below) but later I did not have access to class's methods:

```
typedef boost::variant<TWSoldier*, TWMedic*> myvariant;
...
myvariant Example = FunctionReturningClassReference(2);
std::cout << Example->PrintInfo() << std::endl;

Error   C2819   type 'boost::variant<TWSoldier *>' does not have an overloaded member 'operator ->' 
Error   C2039   'PrintInfo': is not a member of 'boost::variant<TWSoldier *>'   TotalWar
```

Comment: To access class methods you need to know its type. What about using polymorphic classes?

Comment: `variant` is now part of the standard library. Read [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) on how to use it.

Comment: You may use a [Factory method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)

Answer (score 2):

Evg's comment helped, polymorphism was an answer. Luckily all classes that this function could return were of the same "grand-parent" and I simply declared function type as pointer to that grand-parent class and it worked!